# How to create tableview Cell like I message cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working in a project in which i want to implement a tableview cell like a iMessage chat structure.I need to create a custom table view cell with the following pattern.[image]

Comment: Use JSQMessagesViewController..  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Comment: u can create two tableview cell one for right align and other for left align

Comment: Mike Alter yes i can create but how can i create the arrow mark for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create two custom cells (Programmatically or xibs).

- use pdf for bubble image. You can use one image and on other cell you can transform the same image.
- Add label on cell. add constraind to image and label unrelated to each other.
- for text expanding label, set properly for label.numberoflines = 0, linechange to word wrap.

Comment: can you please help me with the code. I dont have idea to draw the mark symbol at the bottom left and top right corners

Comment: You don't have to draw, if you have issue with it. You can simply use pdf format for the image. Pdf because if will give you a vector.